# Exception unhandled within Application.Designer.vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, exception

I have another issue:

I am able to build my VB.NET application. However, when I go to debug it, I get an unhandled exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException occurred   HResult=0x80131509
>   Message=An error occurred creating the form. See
>   Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object.   Source=ProovePC   StackTrace:
>   at ProovePC.My.MyProject.MyForms.Create__Instance__[T](T Instance) in
>   :line 190    at ProovePC.My.MyProject.MyForms.get_Front1()    at
>   ProovePC.My.MyApplication.OnCreateMainForm() in
>   C:\Users\Phillip\source\Workspaces\Upwork
>   Projects\ProoveIt\ProovePC\My Project\Application.Designer.vb:line 35 
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[]
>   commandLine)    at ProovePC.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in
>   :line 81
>
> Inner Exception 1: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to
>   an instance of an object.

The odd part is that it occurs in auto-generated code, in the Application.Designer.vb file. I have confirmed that the constructor is public and that the name of the form matches the name within this file:

```
Namespace My

    'NOTE: This file is auto-generated; do not modify it directly.  To make changes,
    ' or if you encounter build errors in this file, go to the Project Designer
    ' (go to Project Properties or double-click the My Project node in
    ' Solution Explorer), and make changes on the Application tab.
    '
    Partial Friend Class MyApplication

        <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()>  _
        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New(Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationMode.Windows)
            Me.IsSingleInstance = true
            Me.EnableVisualStyles = true
            Me.SaveMySettingsOnExit = true
            Me.ShutDownStyle = Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.ShutdownMode.AfterAllFormsClose
        End Sub

        <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()>  _
        Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()
            Me.MainForm = Global.ProovePC.Front1 'Error occurs here?
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

I am a little lost on this since I am new VB.NET, but I would like to think that the fix is a simple one. For those wondering, I am running visual studio 2017. I should note that I come from a C# background and recently got into vb.net. So please, explain as much as possible.

Edit:

Form Constructor:

```
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    'NewMethod()
    InitializeComponents()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

End Sub
```

Edit:

Ok so here is the interesting part, now I am getting the error on the InitializeComponents function itself within the auto generated constructor of the form. Once I comment this function out, I am able to build and run the application. I only get so far because that application needs hardware to fully run which I have not connected yet.

Now, here is the interesting part, if I were to comment out the constructor, there is a line above it that comes back as undefined reference error:

```
 Public MainStatus As StatusStrip = StatusStrip1 'Error is here now

'Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    'InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

'End Sub
```

For those wondering, I am now in the front1.vb file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was a property within the form control that was being set to nothing when it needs to be set to Me.

As for the random line of code, `Public MainStatus As StatusStrip = StatusStrip1` I think that it was accidentally copy pasted there as the variable is only used at that line. I commented it out and everything builds good now.

Comment: For me, in the overrides OnCreateMainForm() method I used the 'New' keyword to resolved this issue, i.e. Me.MainForm = New Global.NameSpace.Form